# Call Javascript function after defined interval

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developing MVC 5 Asp.Net Razor application. I want to call a javascript function after every 1 minute during the user visit on my site.

Uptil now I created this:

```
window.setInterval(function () {

    }, (1 * 60 * 1000));
```

I tried to put it in _Layout, but I guess it reloads with page change so timer restarts again. Can anyone tell the exact place where I should put this function?

User is changing pages during his visit to my site. What is the best place to put this function so that it gets called after 1 minute exactly again and again?

Answer (score 0):

Every time your visitors follow a link to a new ASP.NET MVC rendered page in your site the browser will download a new HTML document from your site and execute all the linked JavaScript from scratch. There's nowhere you can put your code as-is so that it will execute every minute in spite of page reloads.

If events spaced one minute apart are an essential feature then the best workaround I can think of is to store some flag in the browser's local storage or a cookie to say when the event should fire.

```
// The code you want to execute every minute
var workFunction = function () { /* Your code here */ };

// Find any currently set event timeout by a previous page,
// or default to now
var getNextEvent = function () { 
    var nextStored = localStorage.nextEvent;
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    var when = nextStored != null ? (nextStored - now) : 0;
    if (when <= 0) {
        when = 0;
    }
}    

var timeoutHandler = function () {
    // Do the work
    workFunction();

    // Set the next event for if the browser *doesn't* navigate
    setTimeout(timeoutHandler, 60000);

    // Record when the next event should fire,
    // in case the browser navigates in the mean time
    var nextToStore = (new Date()).getTime() + 60000;
    localStorage.nextEvent = nextToStore;
}

// Start the events off
setTimeout(timeoutHandler, getNextEvent());
```